# Can't find symbol sqlite3_enable_load_extension after install PHP on macOS Monterey via brew

Tags: php, macos, apache, homebrew, macos-monterey

install php via brew, follow the instructions like this

```
To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:
    LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

Finally, check DirectoryIndex includes index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

The php.ini and php-fpm.ini file can be found in:
    /usr/local/etc/php/8.1/

To restart php after an upgrade:
  brew services restart php
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /usr/local/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.0: 512 files, 79.9MB
==> Running `brew cleanup php`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```

to enable php and [this](https://www.simplified.guide/macos/apache-php-homebrew-codesign) to sign the php.so.

After this, when i run `apachectl configtest`, I got **error** like this
`httpd: Syntax error on line 190 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so, 0x000A): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so\n  Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib`

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for 2 days until I finally gave up.
This might not be the answer you're looking for but I installed Apache via Brew and used that httpd instead of the one that came with the OS.
Had everything up and running in 10 minutes after that.

Comment: Thanks bro. If use `htttpd` instead of the default `Apache`, it's working. Now, i just use `phpstorm` to auto deploy the code to remote test server and use `xdebug` for debug.